# Join where is not working

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Given Below code is not working. we have received ajax for $servid,$appid and

when we $query to print this will us array value but with where it is not give me value.

please check it

```
public function editable($servid,$appid) {

        $result = array();
        $this->db->select('s1.*,t4.service_id,t4.appt_id');
        $this->db->from('service s1');
        $this->db->join('appointment_animal_services t4','s1.id=t4.service_id');
        $this->db->where('t4.appt_id', $appid);
        $this->db->where('t4.service_id' ! = 's1.id');
        $this->db->where('t4.service_id' ! = $servid);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        e($query);

    }
```

Comment: You have `'s1.id=t4.service_id'` in your join, but `'t4.service_id' ! = 's1.id'` in your where. Don't those cancel each other out?

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN  clause has

```
s1.id=t4.service_id
```

But your WHERE clause has

```
t4.service_id ! = s1.id
```

Both together will result in 0 records. Comment the 2nd line and see what you get.

Comment: You need to define the query to figure out what is happening. Dont just print error from database. Tell the error code so that people can investigate. 

The above query that you have mentioned is a contradiction. will always give 0 records.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `t4`.`service_id` ! = s1.id AND `t4`.`service_id` ! =' at line 5

Comment: @LalitDogra - It looks like you're not comparing the data types properly.  If both are of same datatype then you dont need quotes. Just make your query consistent.

Comment: -$result = array();
        $this->db->select('s1.*,t4.service_id,t4.appt_id');
        $this->db->from('service s1');
        $this->db->join('appointment_animal_services t4','s1.id=t4.service_id');
        $this->db->where('t4.appt_id', $this->post("appid",true));
        $this->db->where('t4.service_id != s1.id');        
        $this->db->where('t4.service_id !=' $this->post("servid",true)); 
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        e($query);

Comment: this is how i am doing to get the data but still have some small problem please check

Answer (score -1):

you are joining your table through
`'s1.id' and 't4.service_id'`
and your where clause is
`'t4.service_id' != 's1.id'`
so result will be null, 
Remove the 2nd where clause.